# How can I draw 3-d plot with this dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas, reshape

I edited the question :

my data looks like this

```
       m/z    300  301  302  303  …  1249
Rt
7.01            0    0    0   2.34 …  0 
7.23            0    19.29 0  0    …  0     
7.34            2.43 0    0   0    …  2.34 
7.46            0    10.32 2.31 0  …  0
.
.
33.1314            0     0    24242.23 0  0
```

I would like to draw 3d plot where x = m/z(300 to 1249) y= R/t(7.01 to 33.1314) and z = the value where not 0 in the table(Intensity), with z as height on 3d plot.

Comment: have a look at `plt.contourf` for plotting from orginal data. Also, for reshaping the data, `stack()` and filter the non-zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[300, 7.0034],
          [300, 10.232],
          [0, 999.9],
          [301, 7.00023],
          [301, 7.00046]],
    columns=['wavelength', 'm/z'],
)
non_zero_df = df[df.wavelength!=0]
```

Using [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(non_zero_df['wavelength'], non_zero_df['m/z'])
plt.show()
```

Using [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/)

```
import plotly_express as px

px.scatter(non_zero_df, x='wavelength', y='m/z')
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution in `R`.

Suppose your data looks like this (only first two digits of `m/z` are shown):

```r
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  `m/z` `300` `301`    `302` `303` `1249`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1  7.00  0      0       0     2.34   0   
2  8.00  0     19.3     0     0      0   
3  9.00  2.43   0       0     0      2.34
4 10.0   0     10.3     2.31  0      0   
5 33.1   0      0   24242.    0      0
```

We could use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=matches("\\d+"), names_to="x", names_transform=list(x = as.integer)) %>%
  group_by(`m/z`) %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  slice_min(x)
```

to obtain

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   m/z [5]
  `m/z`     x    value
  <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
1  7.00   303     2.34
2  8.00   301    19.3 
3  9.00   300     2.43
4 10.0    301    10.3 
5 33.1    302 24242.
```

Next we are using `ggplot2` to get a scatter-plot:

```r
ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=`m/z`, color=value)) + 
  geom_point()
```